# Converting this implicitly using an user-defined conversion operator

Tags: c++, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

Let's say I have the following code:

```
class Base
{
};

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(Base* base)
    {
    }
};

class BarBase
{
public:
    operator Base*()
    {
        return base;
    }

private:
    Base* base;
};

class Bar : public BarBase
{
public:
    Bar()
    {
        Foo* foo = new Foo(this);
    }
};
```

The code fails to compile with the following error on GCC 6.3:

```
prog.cpp: In constructor ‘Bar::Bar()’:
prog.cpp:30:26: error: no matching function for call to ‘Foo::Foo(Bar*)’
   Foo* foo = new Foo(this);
                          ^
```

`BarBase` that `Bar` derives from has an user-defined conversion operator for `Base*`. Why doesn't `this` get *implicitly* converted to `Base*` using the aforementioned conversion operator?

Comment: @Piotr Skotnicki Why did you remove the C++14 tag? The question was for C++14, which is currently the latest standard the compiler I use supports.

Comment: Because the issue here has nothing to do with the C++14 features.

Comment: @songyuanyao In this case I wanted to know why it's the way it is in the C++14 standard revision, which is the standard version I develop for). It might be slightly different in C++03 or some other C++ standard revision. Always good to be explicit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've correctly defined implicit conversion operator, however it does not apply to a pointer to your object, only to a reference. Change your code to

```
Foo* foo = new Foo(*this);
```

It is not possible to define an implicit conversion operator for a pointer type because conversion operators are required to be non-static member functions and therefore only apply to references.